# How much time before donating blood should I eat food rich with iron?

Tags: nutrition, blood-donation, iron, hemoglobin

I am regular donor and sometimes, they will not accept me because my iron level is too low (hemoglobin level is I believe precisely what is measured, though I am not an expert). They send me home, and tell me to come back in 2 weeks and eat more red meat, and iron rich vegetables.

So, if I wanted to play on the safe side, I could just eat tons of red meat during those 2 weeks, but I am not a great fan of meat in general. My question is, what period of time before donating should I start to eat red meat more frequently if I want to maximise level of hemoglobin for the test? How much does my body take to absorb the iron from the food, and for how long does it stay in my organism?

Separately, is there time in the day when hemoglobin level is expected to be higher?

Comment: Hi user26069, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. However, I do think you could edit this question to be less personal. Nonetheless, there are two other problems with your post. First, questions here work best when there is one question to answer, not 3. Second, questions here are required to show results of prior research. This helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question to remove personal aspects, focus on a single question and to include links to or references to what you've found in your search.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that you're anemic precisely because you're donating too frequently? Wouldn't backing off on the donations be simpler than trying to figure out how to consume more iron?